# In Objective C, is there any cleaner way to test membership against NSSet created on the fly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, set

For example, I remember in Pascal / Delphi language, we can do something like this:

```
if (i in [1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 11]) then
```

I know in Obj C we have `NSSet` and we can test for membership using containsObject selector. But it's way too verbose. And creating `NSSet` on the fly using wrapper still needs a long code (I have to create an `NSArray` object wrapper first, and then create a `NSSet` object from that `NSArray`). Is there any cleaner way to test for membership in Objective C, maybe like:

```
if (i in @[@(1), @(2), @(3), @(6), @(10), @(11)]) { }
```

is still fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small sets, it's probably at least as fast to just search an array. Assuming `i` is a primitive type and not already an `NSNumber`:

```
if ([@[@(1), @(2), @(3), @(6), @(10), @(11)] containsObject:@(i)) {
    ...
}
```

You can get rid of some of those parentheses if your set is really just a bunch of hardcoded constants:

```
if ([@[@1, @2, @3, @6, @10, @11] containsObject:@(i)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh, I never know that array also has this `containsObject` method. Well, the issue is immediately resolved. Thanks!